# printing char* string argument into UnicodeString object

Tags: c++, char, c++builder, unicode-string

Is it possible to print `char*` argument into UnicodeString object via [`printf`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString__printf.html) member function?

Following code gives me a wrong result (damaged string):

```
UnicodeString s;
s.printf(L"%s", "hello");
```

If I specify `L"hello"` instead of `"hello"` it works as expected (strange to me, why it works with `"%s"` specifier, i think it should be `"%ls"`).

Tested on Embarcadero RAD Studio XE and 10 Seattle by assigning `s` string to Caption property of the form's Label.

Comment: There is no `UnicodeString` type in standard C++, so you must be using some extension library. Try consulting that lib's documentation. Also, try `%hs`, which works for at least one `swprintf()` implementation, but that's a shot in the dark...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `%hs` works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, how much do you charge for the crystall ball?

Comment: I suspect the "%s" thing is support for something like Microsofts `TCHAR` where a #define switches between wide-char and narrow-char builds.  So "%ls" is wide char (always), "%hs" is narrow char (always), and "%s" is "whatever the #define has selected".

Comment: @MartinBonner it is quite logical statement, but in practice it does not confirm, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnicodeString::printf()` is a wrapper for the C-style `vsnwprintf()` function.  In all of C++Builder's C-style printing functions, `%s` uses a non-standard implementation - it depends on whether the Narrow or Wide version of the function is being called, whereas in the C standard, `%s` always expects `char*` instead.

In this case, `UnicodeString::printf()` calls the Wide `vsnwprintf()` function, so `%s` expects a `wchar_t*` (however, `%ls` always expects a `wchar_t*`, per C standards, and `%hs` always expects a `char*`, per Borland standards).  This way, in `String::printf()` (and other printing methods), `%s` is supposed to match the character type of `String` - `char*` for `AnsiString`, `wchar_t*` for `UnicodeString`*.

*However, on Android, Embarcadero has not implemented the Wide `vsnwprintf()`, only the Narrow `vsnprintf()`, so `UnicodeString::printf()` (and other printing methods) end up expecting a UTF-8 `char*` for `%s`! (which I reported as [QC #124607](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124607) and [RSP-13285](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13285)).

Comment: `s` specifier does not allow `h` modifier by C standard. Only `%s` (for `char*`) and `%ls` (for `wchar*`) are legal. See `7.21.6.1/8` Also C standard (C11) does not has `vsnwprintf` (with `n`), only `vswprintf` and `vsnwprintf_s`.